# How to get test coverage using django-nose and coverage

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, travis-ci

I am creating an API using DRF, I was able to setup Docker and was also able to integrate Travis CI. Everything was working fine Travis build was passing Until I tried to get Test Coverage that's when I got the error below:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/.coverage'
The command "docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py test"" exited with 1.
```

Dockerfile file

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
LABEL maintainer ="Daniel Otieno"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

manage.py file

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc

    is_testing = 'test' in sys.argv

    if is_testing:
        import coverage
        cov = coverage.coverage(source=['core'], omit=['*/tests/*'])
        cov.set_option('report:show_missing', True)
        cov.erase()
        cov.start()

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

    if is_testing:
        cov.stop()
        cov.save()
        cov.report()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

settings.py

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--cover-erase',
    '--cover-package=core',
]
```

Comment: Believe it is a TravisCI setup issue - so you are mounting ./app into /app and probably USER `user` (docker one) has no system permissions to create a new file. You should check Travis docs for that. Did you tried to use `root` docker user? Dunno maybe this will help.

Comment: Got a similar problem, but my setup for docker users the local system for local dev. Allows for reloading of code without having to run a build. You could try to give all users (read write permissions -- if you are using linux that is) on the folder containing the .coverage file.  That is a security issue which you have to handle properly.